# LINQ include query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm new at LINQ, and i'm normally will resolve this with SQL, but now i'm trying to do the same with linq and i can't figure this out.
I got 3 tables:

> - Orders (OrderID, Number, etc)
> - OrdersDetail (OrderID, ProductID, Quantity, etc)
> - Products (ProductID, Code, Description)

Now i need a list of orders wich contain products matchin a specific code or descripcion string. My SQL will be:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderID IN(SELECT OrderID FROM OrdersDetail WHERE ProductID IN(SELECT ProductID FROM Products WHERE Code LIKE 'FilterText%' OR Descripcion LIKE 'FilterText%'))
```

How do i do this with LINQ? Also is this the best way to do this, specially if Products table are big? Thank you!

Comment: you'll probably get 10 answers because this is simple,  but next time try to include *what you've tried* when you post

Comment: do you have 3 lists or do your objects have relationships to the other objects like in EF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
db.Orders.Where(o=>o.OrderDetails
                        .Any(od=>od.Product.Code.StartsWith("filterText") 
                           || od.Product.Description.StartsWith("filterText")))
          .ToList()
```

Comment: I believe with the specific "LIKE" clause the OP used you may want to consider using "StartsWith" instead of contains. Otherwise this looks like the right answer!

Comment: this is very EF centric isn't it?

Comment: @TMcKeown - Not really.  Anything that exposes the right navigation properties will support this.  `db.Orders` is more implentation-specific, but even that could be anything with a `DataContext` (LINQ2SQL, EF, etc)

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
var q = (from o in Orders
        from d in o.OrderDetails
        from p in d.Product
        where p.Code.StartsWith("your filter") || p.Description.StartsWith("your filter")
        select o);
```

Comment: @AD.Net since d in `o`.OrderDetails it will do inner join, The sql query is just like yours.

Comment: But you still get a cross join don't you?

Comment: @AD.Net Nope, try it. If I wrote that like this it would be a cross join
`from o in Orders 
from d in OrderDetails`